# Does DataInputStream receives only 2048 bytes of data in Android?

Tags: c#, java, android, .net, datainputstream

From PC (server side) the C#.Net application has to sent 22000 bytes of data to an Android device (client side) via Wi-Fi. But `dataInputStream` in Android device is showing only 2048 bytes of it.

```
dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(workerSocket.getInputStream());
byte[] rvdMsgByte = new byte[dataInputStream.available()];
for (int i = 0; i < rvdMsgByte.length; i++)
    rvdMsgByte[i] = dataInputStream.readByte();
String rvdMsgStr = new String(rvdMsgByte);
```

I am confused with the following:

1. Is PC can send only 2048 bytes of data?
2. Or, is Android device has only 2048 bytes of capacity to receive data?
3. Or, Does `dataInputStream` shows only 2048 bytes even after device received all bytes?

   If (data_received <= 2048 bytes)
   Above code works perfect;

Comment: maybe it's in the limitation of `dataInputStream.available()` as the public method `available()` "Returns an estimated number of bytes that can be read or skipped without blocking for more input." according to http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html. try to set the size of the byte array to 22000 if you need it and see if it works...

Comment: @herom I did the same first. I set the byte size to 30000, but it showed EOFException. :)

Comment: I see ;) @Jon Skeet explained it very well, good to hear that it works :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically shouldn't be using `InputStream.available()`. That tells you how much data is available *right now* - which may well not be the whole message, if it's still coming over the network.

If the stream will end at the end of the message, you should simply keep looping, reading a block at a time until you're done (preferrably *not* just reading a byte at a time!). For example:

```
byte[] readFully(InputStream input) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024]; // 8K buffer
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    return output.toByteArray();
}
```

If you need to break your stream up into messages, you should consider how to do that - sending a "message length" prefix before the data is usually the best option.

Once you've read all the data, you should *not* do this:

```
String rvdMsgStr = new String(rvdMsgByte);
```

That will use the platform default encoding to convert the bytes into text. If this is genuinely text data, you should use the string constructor overload which lets you specify the encoding explicitly.

If it's *not* genuinely text data, you shouldn't be trying to treat it as such. If you really need to represent it as a string, use base64.

Also note that there's no need to use `DataInputStream` here, as far as I can tell.

Comment: really good explanaition on that! thanks a lot (even if I'm not the thread owner) ;)

Comment: I'm confused, it this about java or .net-C#? I see those two tags, it looks like the OP is asking about C# and you answered about Java.

Comment: @gdoron: The client is Java, the server is C#.

Comment: As @herom said, this is a good explanation and it solved my problem.
Thanks JonSkeet, for the quick respond. :)
And gdoron, what is OP?

Comment: But I still wonder, is there any way to declare the `byte[] buffer` with the length of the actual data received instead of a fixed number?

Comment: @iKrshnan: Not unless your protocol supplies it, no. The whole point is that it's a *stream* of information - it can go on for as long as the other end wants to put in data.